# Spring injection with @autowired doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i'm building a sample application with Jersey and Spring.

all works good, i can call the Controller that is found, but when i'm trying to access to the service, this is null. But it's autowired with spring, so this should not be null.

This is my RESTController

```
@Path("/RESTExample")
@Component
@Scope("request")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public class RESTResources {

    @Autowired
    protected RESTServices restServices;

    @GET
    @Path("/resource/{id}")
    public Response getResourceWithID(@PathParam("id") Integer resourceID) {
    return EOMUtils.BuildSuccessResponse(restServices.getData(resourceID));

    }

}
```

this is my RESTServices Class

```
@Service
public class RESTServicesImpl implements RESTServices {

    @Autowired
    protected RESTDao restDao;

    @Override
    public String getData(Integer resourceId) {

    return restDao.getData(resourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public String getData() {

    return restDao.getData();
    }
```

and this is my application-context xml configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd">


  <!-- load the properties  -->
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:properties/app.properties" />

  <!--  load all the beans declared with @Component and child annotation into the Spring's IOC Container  -->
  <context:annotation-config />
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.ep.eom.poc.*" />

  <!-- Load the Log4j bean into the IOC Container --> 
  <bean id="eom_log_factory"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CommonsLogFactoryBean">
        <property name="logName" value="eom_log_factory"/>
  </bean>

    <bean id="log4jInitialization"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
   <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
   <property name="arguments">
      <list>
         <value>classpath:/log4j/config/log4j_${envTarget}.xml</value>
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>   


</beans>
```

and this is my maven

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.capgemini.poc</groupId>
    <artifactId>EOM</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>EOM_POC</name>

    <!-- main properties for the project -->
    <properties>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        <jersey-version>2.11</jersey-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <!-- Support for profiles -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-clean</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks>
                                        <!-- config.properties -->
                                        <copy todir="${project.build.outputDirectory}">
                                            <fileset dir="src/main/resources/" includes="**" />
                                        </copy>

                                        <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/log4j/config/log4j_TEST.xml" />
                                        <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/log4j/config/log4j_PRODUCTION.xml" />
                                        <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/log4j/config/log4j_STAGING.xml" />
                                        <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/properties/app_PROD.properties" />
                                        <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/properties/app_STAG.properties" />
                                        <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/properties/app_TEST.properties" />
                                        <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/properties/app_DEV.properties" />

                                        <copy file="src/main/resources/properties/app_DEV.properties" tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/properties/app.properties" />

                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


    <!-- Repository for fetching the libraries -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


        <build>
        <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <wtpversion>1.5</wtpversion>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Specification-Title>${project.name}</Specification-Title>
                            <Specification-Version>${project.artifactId}</Specification-Version>
                            <Implementation-Version>-${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Core FrameWork -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- SLF4J -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Jersey  -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-entity-filtering</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        </dependency>

          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, use "jersey-container-servlet-core"  -->
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        </dependency>

              <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

i can enter in RESTResource classes, but RESTServices class is NULL.

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: from where do you get the instance of `RestResource`?

Comment: Are both classes under the `com.ep.eom.poc.*` package?

Comment: You are using Jersey and you need to properly configure Jersey to use Spring as a DI container. See the [Jersey Reference Guide](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/spring.html).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done spring in forever, but I believe your issue is that you are not loading your `RESTResources` class from the IoC container.

You need to define the `RESTResources` in your application-context and load it from your ApplicationContext.

I see that you have `context:component-scan` for `com.ep.eom.poc.*`. Is `RestResources` under the `com.ep.eom.poc` package?

If you're just trying to grab the class "raw", it won't have the dependencies injected into it.

Comment: yep, i have resolved. I was missing this library in pom:  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
   <version>${jersey-version}</version>
  </dependency>